# Regex pattern help needed to limit the contents of key value pairs

Tags: regex, xsd

I am trying to limit the contents of an xml element using a regex pattern within the schema but I just cant get it working and the more I add the worse it seems to get.

The requirements are as follows:

- The element string can't be longer that 512 characters (This bit's easy but added for completeness)
- The string consists of multiple key value pairs.
- The key value pairs will be separated by '^'
- Each key value pair consists of a 3 character key, followed any number of characters for the value.
- The keys will be separated from the values by '|'

An example of the XML would be:

```
<myElement>
    ABC|This is some value text for key ABC^DEF|This is some value text for key DEF^GHI|This is some value text for key GHI^JKL|This is some value text for key JKL^
</myElement>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the question you say "The key/value pairs will be separated by '^'", but the example shows the key/value pairs terminated by '^', so I'm assuming that's what you want.

The key matches `\w{3}` (3 letters or digits).

The value matches `[^^<]*` (any number of any characters except `^`).

The complete regex is `(\w{3}\|[^^]*\^)*`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this regex expression doesn't work when used in an XSD file. I'm using XMLPad3 as a validation tool and I get an error "Unrecognized Modifier (pos 18)"

Comment: That error message isn't very helpful to me. Is it complaining about the regex itself? If so, is there some documentation somewhere showing details of the regex support?

Comment: You are right, the error message wasn't very useful but I have tracked down the problem through a process of elimination. The '?:' causes a problem when used as part of an xsd patten. Also the complete regex above doesn't match the component parts. My final regex expression was "(\w{3}\|[^^>]*\)*". Thanks for your help.

Comment: @TeamWild: I've replaced the non-capturing group with a capturing group.